# Move C code with struct initialization and assignment to c++ compiler

Tags: c++, c, struct

Why is there no direct assigment during declaration of a struct possible in C++?
I have the following C code that wont work with C++ compiler:

```
static const struct {
    struct structtype1 header;
    struct {
        struct structtype2 intf;
        struct structtype3  src;
    }  foo1, foo2;
}  bar = {
    .header = {
        .byte1 = 0x23,
        .length = 12,
        .count1 = 4,
        .count2 = 4,
    },
    .foo1= {
        .intf = {
            .data =  0x23,
            .len = 2,
            .ep = 3,
                },
        .src= {
            .data =  0x21,
            .len = 4,
            .ep = 2,
        },
        },
        .foo2= {
        .intf = {
            .data =  0x17,
            .len = 11,
            .ep = 2,
                },
        .src= {
            .data =  0x20,
            .len = 2,
            .ep = 1,
        },
        },
};
```

Comment: Designated initializers are a C99 feature which has not been ported to C++.

Comment: You will have to refactor the code

Answer (score 0):

you have two choices:

1.use constructors for that

- this will define values for members but all structs will be the same

  ```
  struct _pnt { int x,y,z;  _pnt() { x=0; y=0; z=0; } };
  _pnt p0,p1,p2;  // all points are initialized to (0,0,0)
  ```

2.use definition as usual it still works in any C++ compiler I used

- I think this is what you want
- Do not forget that the **order of members is the same as in declaration** !!!

  ```
  struct _pnt { int x,y,z; };
  _pnt p0={0.0,0.0,0.0},
       p1={1.0,0.0,0.0},
       p2={0.0,1.0,0.0};
  ```
- problem is you have to init all members not just some !!!